# INNER JOIN issue

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

I am getting the following error from this query:

## 1054 - Unknown column 'sheet_items.color_id' in 'on clause'

```
select sheet_items.sheet_id, sheet_items.quantity, materials.material, colors.color
from sheet_items, materials
inner join colors
on colors.color_id=sheet_items.color_id
where sheet_items.sheet_id=4 and sheet_items.material_id=materials.material_id
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, does `sheet_items` have a column named `color_id`?

Comment: can you paste the schema of those tables? The message is quite clear, you don't have a column named **color_id** in the table **sheet_items**

Comment: I do have a column named color_id, which is why it is an odd error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it structured now, you are trying to inner join Materials with colors, therefore, it does not know what column you are talking about.. try

```
select sheet_items.sheet_id, sheet_items.quantity, materials.material, colors.color
from materials,sheet_items
inner join colors
on colors.color_id=sheet_items.color_id
where sheet_items.sheet_id=4 and sheet_items.material_id=materials.material_id
```

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sheet_items` (
  `sheet_item_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sheet_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `material_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `color_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sheet_item_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your mixing pre & post ANSI92 SQL, try either...

PRE ANSI92

```
select sheet_items.sheet_id, sheet_items.quantity, materials.material, colors.color
from sheet_items, materials, colors
where sheet_items.sheet_id=4 and sheet_items.material_id=materials.material_id AND
colors.color_id=sheet_items.color_id
```

POST ANSI92

```
select sheet_items.sheet_id, sheet_items.quantity, materials.material, colors.color
from sheet_items
inner join materials
on sheet_items.material_id=materials.material_id
inner join colors
on colors.color_id=sheet_items.color_id
where sheet_items.sheet_id=4
```

Either way IMHO the second format is easier to read/understand & debug and will work across all SQL platforms

Answer (score 0):

You have an implicit inner join in your where clause between sheet_items and materials. You should take that out of your where clause and put it into your projection, so that it looks like this:

```
select sheet_items.sheet_id, sheet_items.quantity, materials.material, colors.color from materials
inner join sheet_items on materials.material_id=sheet_items.material_id 
inner join colors on colors.color_id=sheet_items.color_id 
where sheet_items.sheet_id=4
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix up the way you do JOINs, it gets very confusing.

```
SELECT sheet_items.sheet_id, sheet_items.quantity, materials.material, colors.color
FROM
sheet_items
INNER JOIN materials ON materials.id=sheet_items.material_id
INNER JOIN colors ON colors.color_id=sheet_items.color_id
WHERE
sheet_items.sheet_id=4
```